# Shared network folders usage by PHP scripts - is this possible from outside the domain?

Tags: php, networking, filesystems, dns, system-administration

I am having the following difficulties:
Three servers A,B,C : A,B in the same network domain; C in another.
PHP scripts executing on server A write to a shared folder on server B.
The same scripts executing on server C fail to write to server B.

PHP looks something like this:

```
oject->Output('\\\\serverB\\sharedfolder\\file.dummy');
```

Is there any way I can make this script work elegantly on server C?

When I remote-desktop to server C and want to see the contents of `\\serverB\sharedfolder`, a login prompt pops up and asks for a user name and password. This I can provide and subsequently access the shared folder on server B. But how could I do this from a PHP script? Is it possible?

Comment: PHP does not natively support the Samba protocol (windows file transfers). Does your object implement it?

Comment: the object in question is an instance of FPDF. The open-source PDF generating component.
it's something like pdf->Output('\\\\server\\share\\file.pdf','F'); Don't know about Samba...

Comment: All of the machines involved are running Windows. No Samba needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest option with security in mind would be to write the content from server C in to a socket where server A,B reside and have an additional script which will save the content written from the socket to your shared folder.....

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Comment: our IT team has rearranged the servers so that it automagically started to work, but I like the proposed solution. This seems like an elegant and secure solution.

Answer (score 1):

The formats are:

- UNC — `\\servername\sharename%username:password`
- URL — `smb://[[domain;]username[:password]@]server[/share[/path]]`

Comment: Provided above URL is not working on windows 10. Windows10 silly suggests to look at marketplace for appropriate application

Comment: @Velaro AFAIK SMB is not enabled by default in Win10, you need to go to _Windows Features_ and enable _SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support_